# Unable to add 4 int64 crosstab columns into a result column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, axis, crosstab

I cross-tabled a column which gave me 4 different columns with an `int64` value, but occupation show up as if though it was still in crosstab.
first column is the Year and starts at `1999` thinks it an index.
I have tried every way and am unable to add them up. Here is a sample:

```
cone.head()
occupation, music, gov, media, other
   Year
   1999      150    2     11     3
    cone["result"] = cone.apply(lambda row: row['Year':'Music',
    'Gov','Media','other'].sum(),axis=1)

 if not isinstance(self.index, MultiIndex):
--> 968             raise ValueError('Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex')
    969 
    970         # If key is contained, would have returned by now

ValueError: ('Can only tuple-index with a MultiIndex', 'occurred at index 1999')
```

Comment: What is `print (cone.info())` ?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 17 entries, 1999 to 2015
Data columns (total 4 columns):
Acting_Comedy_Music        17 non-null int64
Government and Politics    17 non-null int64
Media                      17 non-null int64
Other                      17 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(4)
memory usage: 680.0 bytes
None

Comment: Can you test `cone["result"] = cone[['Music',
    'Gov','Media','other']].sum(axis=1)` ?

Comment: 1250             if not(self.name == 'loc' and not raise_missing):
   1251                 not_found = list(set(key) - set(ax))
-> 1252                 raise KeyError("{} not in index".format(not_found))
   1253 
   1254             # we skip the warning on Categorical/Interval

KeyError: "['other', 'Gov', 'Music'] not in index"

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-234-5bdab440dce2> in <module>()
----> 1 cone["result"] = cone[['Music', 'Gov','Media','other']].sum(axis=1)

Comment: Here main question is - need sum all columns to new column like `cone["result"] = cone.sum(axis=1)` ?